# Subtracting time down rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds the end time, activity id, record number. What I need to do is subtract record 2's time from record 1' time, record 4's time from record 3's time.

```
table data 
started                 activity Id record Id
11/14/2013 11:06:29 PM  1257            1
11/15/2013 2:09:57 PM   1291            2
11/18/2013 4:26:34 AM   1257            3
11/18/2013 4:48:53 PM   1291            4
11/19/2013 2:54:52 AM   1257            5
11/19/2013 3:42:00 PM   1291            6
11/21/2013 2:24:38 AM   1257            7
11/21/2013 2:08:06 PM   1291            8
```

I have no idea how to do this, can someone please assist.

Comment: So what would your expected output be?

Comment: New Rows For subtracting time

[recordID = recordId "-" recordId, SecondsTimeOn
1-2, 54208
3-4,44539
5-6,46028
7-8,42208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions in SQL reference one row at a time.

So when you want an expression to reference two rows in SQL, you need a self-join to transform  two rows into one row:

```
SELECT TO_SECONDS(t2.started) - TO_SECONDS(t1.started) AS difference_in_seconds
FROM `table data` AS t1
JOIN `table data` AS t2
  ON t2.record_id = t1.record_id + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your id's are assigned sequentially and define what you mean by "record 1" and "record 2", you can do this with aggregation:

```
select max(case when id % 2 = 1 then id end) as id1,
       max(case when id % 2 = 0 then id end) as id2,
       to_seconds(max(t2.started)) - to_second(min(t2.started)) as diff
from data
group by floor(id - 1)/2;
```

This assumes that the times are assigned sequentially so the difference is never negative.  If that could be the case, then use `case` instead:

```
select max(case when id % 2 = 1 then id end) as id1,
       max(case when id % 2 = 0 then id end) as id2,
       (to_seconds(max(case when id % 2 = 0 then started end)) -
        to_seconds(max(case when id % 2 = 1 then started end))
       ) as diff
from data
group by floor(id - 1)/2;
```

Comment: This might be closer to what I am looking for! I need to disregard the record number as they may be out of order - I subtract or add rows based on times. - as in your second example. Can you tell me what the % means AND how can I make sure it it picking up the row ahead

Comment: The `%` is the mod operator.  It returns the integer remainder when two integers are divided.  If you have a different problem from the one in the question, I would suggest that you add another question and -- include a SQL Fiddle with example data.